# How do I output the result return from cv2.read() into a file

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I first read an image using im = cv2.read(image) and it supposed to return an np array. So I did im.dump('output.txt') in which the output file gave me a bunch of junk

How do I visualize the array reading from input image?
Any TensorFlow method I can use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img = cv2.imread( image_file )` is the correct way to read an image. You can then `plt.imshow()` to see the image, or use csv to output the numeric values to a file.

Code (tested in Jupyter Notebook):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img = cv2.imread( "./angelina jolie happy.jpg" )
print( img )
with open( "image_array.csv", 'wb') as f:
    w = csv.writer( f )
    for x in xrange( img.shape[ 0 ] ):
        for y in xrange( img.shape[ 1 ] ):
            w.writerow( img[ x ][ y ])

plt.imshow( cv2.cvtColor( img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB ) )
```

Outputs:

> [[[192 170 164]
>     [191 169 164]
>     [191 168 166]
>     ...
>     [109 152 201]
>     [ 59 125 196]
>     [ 66 117 167]]]

[image]

and creates the file "image_array.csv" with the pixel values like this:

> 192,170,164
>   191,169,164
>   191,168,166
>   184,161,159
>   180,156,156
>   183,160,158
>   190,167,165
>   189,167,162
>   174,150,144
>   etc.